# Selenium: How to stop RemoteRunner.html from getting invoked

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I am using selenium for one for my Java applications on linux.  The application invokes a mozilla browser, fills login details (username and password), and then submits the form.  I am able to achieve this using selenium, but every time a url is selected 2 instances of mozilla is getting invoked.  One instance is that of the url selected and the other instance is a RemoteRunner.html which has selenium command history and other details.

I don't want this page to be invoked.  Is there a way to stop this page from getting invoked?

Thanks and Regards,
Sunil.

Answer (score 2):

The RemoteRunner window is required as it is controlling the application under test within the other window. You can run Selenium in a single window using the command line option `multiWindow=false` however this uses frames, which can sometimes cause issues with the application under test.